# Meromorphic function - Countably infinite or finite number of poles?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, meromorphic-functions

I am having trouble reconciling the following two questions:

- [Can it be proved that a Meromorphic function only has a countable number of poles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962314/can-it-be-proved-that-a-meromorphic-function-only-has-a-countable-number-of-pole?rq=1)
- [$f$ meromorphic on $\mathbb{\hat{C}}$ $\implies$ $f$ has a finite number of poles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772908/f-meromorphic-on-mathbb-hatc-implies-f-has-a-finite-number-of-pole?rq=1)

One seems to show that meromorphic functions have at most **countably many** poles while the other proofs that it is a **finite number**. My question is essentially whether the latter is generally true or whether there can be a meromorphic function with a **countably infinite number** of poles? If so, under what conditions is this possible?

My suspicion is that it is all about the domain, e.g. that functions that are meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ can have infinitely many poles while meromorphic functions on [$\hat{\mathbb{C}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) cannot. Then all functions which are meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and have infinitely many poles are not meromorphic on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. Are these statements correct?

Comment: Yes, you have answered your own question.

Comment: it depends on the definition of meromorphic function

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks! I would happily give that line a green tick if it was an answer ;)

Comment: @Masacroso could you elaborate?